# Can i use current logged in users detail to pass to Tableau Web data connector for authentication?

Tags: tableau-api, dreamfactory

I have created Web data connector which fetches some data from DreamFactory API. but to get those data it need to send userid and password. Can i send the current tableau logged in user data to the web data connector?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Is the web data connector hosted on your tableau server or on a different server?

Comment: No i have published it to the Tableau online.We don't have Tableau server.